# Convergence of quantiles based on estimates

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $D_\theta$ denote a distribution with parameter $\theta$, that has density wrt. Lebesgue measure. Let $X$ have distribution $D_\theta$ and let $\hat{\theta}_n$ be a sequence of estimates of $\theta$, converging to $\theta$ in probability (or almost surely if that is required).

Let $Q_\theta(p)$ denote the quantile function of $D_\theta$. Do we have

$$
P(X \in [Q_{\hat{\theta}_n}(p_1), Q_{\hat{\theta}_n}(p_2)]) \to P(X \in [Q_\theta(p_1), Q_\theta(p_2)])
$$

for every $p_1 \leq p_2$?

If not, what further assumptions do we need? Continuity of $Q$ in $\theta$ seems like it might do the trick but can we infer that from simply knowing that $D_\theta$ is absolutely continuous wrt. Lebesgue measure? Any ideas?